# Why filter 'posts_join', 'posts_where', and 'posts_fields' not affect on single post request?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I created some custom query use filter above, but why not affected on single posts? The filter work well in posts loop.

Here example code.

```
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'my_join' );

function my_join( $join ) {
   $join .= " some sql ";
   return $join;
}
```

Comment: This code is affect only post loop, you need to work on single post code.

Comment: Yap, i found the solutions! If your working with REST API in WP, change or override function get_item() on WP Rest post controller. Why? Because get item use get_post() so 'posts_join' table not affected. Change get_post() with new WP_Query() for more post data.